# Parsing CSV file in Windows Server 2008 64 C#

Tags: c#, csv

I'm having some trouble parsing a *.CSV file in windows server 2008 64bit version. The problem it that Jet OLEDB 4.0 doesn't read the header row, presented in the CSV.

That means, that when I try to access one of the columns like this:

```
DataTable tbl = GetCsvData();
string sd = tbl.Rows[0]["id"].ToString();
```

The program throws an exception, saying that the column does not belong in the datable.

I'm using the following code:

```
public DataTable GetCsvData() {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(this.fileName);
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
             "Data Source=" + file.DirectoryName + "\\;" +
             "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(;)\";";
        OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        objConn.Open();
        OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", file.Name), objConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(objCmdSelect);
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable("CSVData");
        adp.Fill(tbl);
        objConn.Close();
        objConn.Dispose();
        return tbl;
    }
```

As you can see, the Extended Properties are correct: "HDR=Yes", this forces the Jet engine to read the header row on the CSV file.

The problem is really strange because I can read the same CSV file on my development machine ( Windows XP SP3 ), with absolutely no problem.

I think this is a problem derived to the 64 bit version of Windows server 2008.

I checked the versions of the msjet40.dll file on both the server and local machine:

```
Windows XP SP3 => 4.0.9551
Windows Server 2008 64 bit => 4.0.9755
```

The problem isn't on the CSV file, it's in the driver provided by Microsoft ( at least is what I think ), since I can read the CSV file perfectly on my machine.

Does one has any idea a way to solve this problem? I googled a lot, but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks..

Comment: Can you verify it is the driver by connecting to the data from an external app from both systems? For example, Excel or a SQL Linked query (chances are that you won't have Excel on your server).

Comment: I don't have Excel on the server...that's for sure...And I can't verify that.. thanks..

Comment: The JET driver is not available in 64-bit mode.  Did you force your program to run in 32-bit mode?

Comment: Yes I did... when I ran in 64.bit mode, the web application would throw an Exception saying that the Jet Driver wasn't registered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at "[Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)" or "[FileHelpers library](http://www.filehelpers.com/)" instead of using JET OLEDB.

Comment: I went to "Fast CSV Reader", it works quite well the parser is working perfectly now.. thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I find the Jet drivers to be so inconsistent that I usually read CSVs as text files.  CSVs are fairly easy to parse, and I never have to worry about driver problems.

Comment: Don't roll your own solution, there are proven and tested ones (see my answer). Reading CSV can be more complicated than you'd think at first (see "Fast CSV Reader" link in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a great answer, but if it turns out to be the driver then you might be able to work around it by using http://www.filehelpers.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) that's [built into](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx) the .NET framework?

Yes folks, it's part of Microsoft.VisualBasic, but it's still a totally supported part of .Net.